How to turn off auto capitalization cental in SwiftUI?
How to turn off auto capitalization for textfield cental in SwiftUI? Tryied in Info.plist bí setting None for UITextAutocapitalizationType does not work.

What's wrong with textInputAutocapitalization(.never)?


You can directly specify the autocapitalization type for each TextField:

TextField("Enter text", text: $text)
    .textInputAutocapitalization(.never)


You can also use TextFieldStyle for this purpose:

struct CustomTextFieldStyle: TextFieldStyle {
    func _body(configuration: TextField<Self._Label>) -> some View {
        configuration
            .textInputAutocapitalization(.never)
    }
}

// Apply it to textfields
TextField("Enter text", text: $text)
    .textFieldStyle(CustomTextFieldStyle())

